# How to pass checked box details to next page in PHP?

Tags: php, forms

I have a dynamic table which created depending on the database details, it has four columns which takes the information from the database to display on table.
The problem is, I have a **checkbox** column at the extreme left of this table and I need to design the page in such a way that, once the checkbox is clicked, I should get that particular row information directed to the next page. Also there may be more than one checkboxes clicked at the same time.

Can anyone please help me on this wrt PHP or at least the approach/algorithm as how I can go ahead with this.

Comment: Save the checkbox details in an array, and then save the array details in a session, after using it you can `unset()` that particular session variable...

Comment: Store the comma separated values (CSVs) in a variable on php and pass them to a function on the next page? Or just pass the CSVs as HTTP body parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function (){
    window.onload=function(){
        updateTextArea();
    }
    function updateTextArea() {
        var allVals = [];
        $('#c_b :checked').each(function() {
            allVals.push($(this).val());  
        });
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'Ads-Search.php?search='+allVals,
            success: function(html) 
            {
                $('#1').html(html);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<body>
<div id='c_b'>
</div>

<div id='1'>
</div>
</body>
```

as soon as u click on check box , control will pass to another file using ajax and u will perform         ur operations over there

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for all your inputs. But still not getting how exactly it will work with PHP. Firstly when the next button is click from the table page (first page) is there should be some mechanism wherin 1) it will check all the CHECKBOXes which are clicked? and then take the data of thos and put it in next page, or 2) dynamically whener any user clicks on the CHECKBOX button it will keep its data. Please let me know whethr there are any more advanced mechnism available in PHP, or any other code/system available with any1 for this purpose!!